# Synaptic error when attempting to downgrade Apache

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd, synaptic

I'm having an issue with Apache 2.4.10 and PHP 5.6.2.  Specifically, Apache has suffered from segmentation faults when I attempt to access certain files on my localhost through the browser (full details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641317/apache-2-4-segmentation-fault-when-accessing-certain-localhost-symfony-2-php-fil), in case anyone wants to check it out).

In an attempt to rectify the problem so I can actually get some work done, I'm trying to downgrade both my Apache and PHP to earlier versions.  I'm using Mint 17, so I went through the package manager to remove the existing Apache 2.4.10 and PHP 5.6.2.  I then removed the PPA that I got those packages from, and instead installed the dotdeb repo as it tends to be a few updates behind.  When attempting to install Apache 2.4.7 from dotdeb, I get the following error:

[image]

How do I fix this?  When I removed Apache 2.4.10, I marked it for complete removal.  I'd think that would get rid of all the related packages/dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by going through the package list and seeing that despite selecting 'Complete Removal' for Apache 2, several dependencies still remained.  After removing those, I was able to install a downgraded version of Apache (2.4.7).